# Scala XML output an quotation mark ' " '

Tags: xml, scala, quotation-marks

I'm trying to output to an .html file some info.

I'm reading from a file and getting values to know how much items my tables are going to have, like this:

```
val classes = (x \\ "class").length
```

I wanted to use the colspan with the value that I got, but I need to insert the quotation mark ' " '.

```
 var classe = {
  for (file <- x \ "java-class-file")
    yield <tr><th colspan="{classes}">{ file \ "@name" }</th></tr>
         {...}
}
```

But it doesn't work since its need something like:

```
colspan="2"
```

Instead I get:

```
colspan={classes}
```

How can I do it, since ' " ' doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the syntax is `<th colspan={classes}>` (no quotation marks). You probably want `colspan={classes.toString}`, though, since `classes` is an `Int`.

Comment: Yep sorry it was hard for me to explain myself, but you got it and the `.toString` solved my problem! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: in Scala's XML literal syntax you can interpolate attribute values by using braces without quotation marks:

```
scala> val x = "foo"
x: String = foo

scala> <elem x={x}/>
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <elem x="foo"/>
```

The value needs to be a string, though, so in your case you want `colspan={classes.toString}`.